# Swapping of images in ScrollView In Iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

Hi i am New to iphone programming
i have a scrollview and the images on that ,and i want to swap the images in the scrollview ,please help me out.

Comment: why you are using scrollview for swapping images?

Comment: you need to develop your custom logic for this n also require to store locations of each image n need to update that while you do any changes, like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [UIScrollView Class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) and download Scrolling.zip from there..

Comment: i want to use drag and drop of images on scrollview